# Oracle 10g TNS listener working but not working

Tags: database-connection, oracle-xe

My application is unable to connect to my local Oracle 10g database (Windows 7) but I cannot figure out which aspect of the configuration is wrong.  I can simulate the connection problem using sqlplus.

The following works:

```
sqlplus <username>/<password>
```

If I append the TNS alias, however, it does not work:

```
sqlplus <username>/<password>@XE
```

It appears to connect but then hangs, never giving me a command prompt.  If I execute a "tnsping xe", it appears that the TNS information is all configured properly.  How does one diagnose what the problem is?  I have poked around in logs, event viewer, etc, but still have no clear picture.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

sqlplus user/password@//IP:port/sid

port is usually 1521 depending on your installation.

e.g sqlplus user/password@//127.0.0.1:1521/XE